# How to list all JSON keys in a file to identify database column names?

Tags: python, json

I plan to use Python to load JSON into an SQLite database. Is there a way to list all of the keys from a JSON file (not from a string) using Python?

I want to determine what columns I will need/use in my SQLite table(s), without having to manually read the file and make a list. Something along the lines of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` in SQL Server, or the `FINDALL` in Python for XML.

I'm not looking to use other technologies, I'm sticking to Python, JSON, and SQLite on purpose.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax produced the desired results:

```
import json

with open('my-file.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for i in data:
    print(i.keys())
```